# Return the exact value of a CSS property by javascript in % form across all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve a cross-browser if/else statement. The issue is I'm checking the 'top' property on an element, and Chrome & safari return the css value, while Opera & Firefox always return it in pixels no matter what. Is there any way I can read the CSS directly and use jQuery or javascript to return the value of 'top' on an element as it's entered in the .css file?

I need a unified value returned in terms of a %. The problem is that Firefox converts it to pixels.

Here's my code:

```
if ($('#wrapper').position().top == '-100%') {
        // Do Stuff
}
```

This works in chrome since chrome returns -100% in the instance. But firefox returns something like `'-720px'`. It converts that percentage into pixels.

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why do you need the source value?

Comment: Because Firefox returns pixels & chrome/safari returns whatever is in the code. I just need a unified return from both browsers. It doesn't matter what it is, as long as they give the same thing.

Comment: I'll edit my question...

Comment: Can you not parse the units (px, em, % etc.) and convert it to a standard unit?

Comment: How would I convert it to a standard unit? My top is a percentage, so you'd have to know how tall the browser window was at all times. That can really slow down a site if you're constantly checking for that on window resize.

Comment: Have you tried it to see that it is slow - I doubt it would cause any issues. Also, the % is relative to the element's parent, so you would simply need to use `parent().height()` - you don't need to worry about resize events.

Comment: Alright, how could I convert the px to % or % to pixels?

Comment: (browser height / px) * 100. Cool, this could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, you can't get back the %, but you might be able to figure it out by dividing the pixels returned from the css divided by the height.

```
var top = parseInt($('#ID').css('top')) / $('#ID').parent().height() * 100;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. It's sad you have to fetch and convert pixels though. Firefox & Chrome should both return the same value, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get what's entered in the CSS file, but you can simply do some parsing of the return value.  The below should standardize the values for you and you can then do whatever comparison you need to make (uses JQuery).

`parseInt($("#elementId").css("top").replace("px", ""))`

Comment: I don't really understand. Check out my code in my question (just updated) and see if this still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **parseInt()** method to return a numeric value from the CSS attribute.

```
var top = parseInt($("#someElement").css("top"));
```

Comment: This wouldn't help as 100% would get parsed as 100, and 720px as 720. OP wants the returned value to be in the same units, irrespective of browser

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using @JacksonGariety?

Comment: It would be helpful if you opened up a jsFiddle